# SQL negation in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, negation

Hi I'm trying to solve a problem with negating data I have two tables

Classes:

```
+----+----------+--+
| id |   name   |  |
+----+----------+--+
|  1 | 'First'  |  |
|  2 | 'Second' |  |
+----+----------+--+
```

Lists:

```
+----+----------+--+
| id | id_class |  |
+----+----------+--+
|  1 |        1 |  |
+----+----------+--+
```

class id references id_class

and I want to select the data that is not in the lists table. I tried this:

```
  SELECT c.name FROM classes c JOIN lists l ON (l.id_class=c.id) WHERE l.id_class!=c.id
```

But no result, guess it's not correct Any solutions ?

Comment: Try `not in` or `not exists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
from classes c 
left join lists l on (l.id_class=c.id) 
where l.id_class is null
```

or, you can also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select c.id, c.name
from classes c 
where not exists (select *
                  from lists l
                  where l.id_class=c.id)
```